# Need helping modifying PHP code to accept 2 possible passwords

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

can anyone help me understand how to modify this code so that it accepts two potential passwords? I am trying to phase out the old one but don't want to immediately block all users who have the old one. I don't know PHP, and received this code from someone who was kind enough to provide it. This code is for a personal portfolio site. Thanks for your help.

```
<?

$password = "";


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $password = $_POST['password'];


    //if passwordis correct (redirect)

    if($password == "ABC") { 

        //redirect (cant have output anything to page for it to work)

        header('location: http://www.portfolio.com/rewards.html');


    //if($password != "ABC") {

    }else{

        //set error message and display form again

        $error['password'] = "Please re-enter the password.";

    }


}

?>
```

Comment: Why not use a second `if` branch?

Comment: Do you mean you have a shared password that everyone on your team knows, and you want to add a second shared password? If so, you are looking for OR which in PHP is `||`: https://3v4l.org/o3a5Q